# Homomorphism of matrix groups is determined by its differential

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

May I use some help on how to prove the Ex 7.15 in page 111 from "Matrix groups for undergraduate, 1st" by Tapp ?

> Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be matrix groups with Lie algebras $g_1$ and $g_2$ respectively. Let $f:G_1\rightarrow G_2$ be a $C^1$ homomorphism. Denote the differential of $f$ at unit element $I$ by $df_I:g_1\rightarrow g_2$. Prove that for all $v\in g_1$,
>   $$f(e^v)=e^{df_I(v)}.$$

I attempted to expand the exponential on both sides using the formula

> $e^v = I+v+1/2v^2+1/6v^3 +...$

and got

> $f(v)=df_I(v)$

which I have no clue to prove.

Any tips ?

Comment: There are many ways to define the exponential map and the differential of a function and how you answer this question is gonna depend on which of those definitions you are using.  I don't have access to Tapp's book, can you say what your definitions are?

Comment: @Jim Thanks for interest. The matrix exponential is defined as I wrote in the post. The differential is defined as in manifold, which is a linear map from a tangent space to another tangent space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $v\in g_1$ then $t\mapsto e^{tv}$ is a Lie group homomorphism
from $\Bbb R$ (under addition) to $G_1$, and **all** Lie group
homomorphisms from $\Bbb R$ to $G_1$ are of this form. Take the
composition with this with $f$ and we get the a Lie group homomorphism
from $\Bbb R$ to $G_2$. It must equal $t\mapsto e^{tw}$ for some $w\in G_2$.
But considering the derivative ay zero gives us $w=df(v)$. Thus
$$f(e^{tv})=e^{t df(v)}.$$
Now take $t=1$.

Comment: Thanks ! I got it. And there is typo at the third line to last. It should be **at zero**.